# All cvs operations in a mounted folder yield "cannot get working directory" error

Tags: cvs

I cannot get cvs to work when running in a Linux folder mounted to a folder on a Windows server.  The Windows folder has an existing cvs module hierarchy, but any action from the Linux side such as "cvs status", "cvs update", etc., will produce an error like this:

```
cvs [update aborted]: cannot get working directory: No such file or directory
```

The folder is mounted read/write, and at a bash prompt I can copy files, edit them, delete them, create directories, etc.

I read somewhere that CVS uses getcwd(3), so I wrote a little C program to test whether getcwd would work while in that folder, and it worked fine.

My Linux and CVS versions are:

> SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (i586)
>   Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.12.12 (client/server)

I'm stumped.  What can I try to get the Linux-side cvs commands to work?

Comment: I am still trying to figure this out.  I thought the problem might be due to line-ending differences between Linux and Windows.  On the Windows side, the original CVS sandbox was originally created with TortoiseCVS, and the line endings in all of the hidden CVS files are CRLF.  When I access the sandbox from a mount on a Linux system, maybe the cvs client is getting confused by the unexpected line-endings.

Comment: The line-ending idea didn't seem to pan out.  However, I discovered the "-t" option for cvs to show a command trace.  In the failed case, the only line shown in the trace is "-> main: Session ID is ...".  In the success case, the next two lines after that are `-> main loop with CVSROOT=/home/cvs`, followed by `open_connection_to_server( :ext:username@domain.com:/home/cvs)`.  It looks like the "main loop" is unable to resolve /home/cvs.